# .htaccess Multiple subdirectory rewriting to www-root

Tags: .htaccess, web, directory, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have the following folder structure:

- www-root

  - Backend

    - Config
    - Etc
  - Frontend

    - Administration
    - StoreFront

I would like to be able to access the directories from the main url and hiding the subdirectories in between.

So the administrative part I should be able to access like this:

```
 http://localhost/Administration/
```

The main page which is stored in the subdirectory "StoreFront", I want to be able to access from the root:

```
 http://localhost
```

This is the code in my .htaccess file so far:

```
# Store Redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Frontend/StoreFront
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/StoreFront/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /Frontend/StoreFront/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Administration
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/Administration/$2
```

This code however does not work correctly. It rewrites every file except the index.php file to the Administration subdirectory. One side note: php files which are in the backend directory should remain "includable" from the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell upfront you that what you're trying to achieve is **mission impossible**, now let me tell you why. You have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/StoreFront/$1
```

and down further you have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/Administration/$2
```

**You cannot have `.*` going to both the places**. You need to distinguish these 2 paths somehow.

It is besides the point that you have other problems also e.g.:

1. Not using `L` (LAST) flag wherever needed
2. Using `$2` instead of `$1` in 2nd rule

**EDIT:** Based on your comments:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(Administration(?:/.*|))$ /Frontend/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /Frontend/StoreFront/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Frontend/StoreFront
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/StoreFront/$1 [L]
```

Comment: For the second one I just want to rewrite the Administration directory to `/Frontend/Administration/`. I don't want to rewrite every file in the administration directory to the root. Just the directory itself.
So `http://localhost/Administration` actually is: `http://localhost/Frontend/Administration/` and thus in the browser shows up as `http://localhost/Administration`.

Comment: Ok I will provide my answer based on this.

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate it. I have one small problem still though. If I don't put a slash after Administration, I get a 404. So `http://localhost/Administration` produces a 404, but `http://localhost/Administration/` does not.

Comment: Almost working except that if now I don't put a slash behind it it shows `http://localhost/Frontend/Administration/` in the url field. The page shows up alright, just the wrong url in the browser field. It happens only when there is no slash behind it... if there is a slash behind it it simply shows `http://localhost/Administration/`.

Comment: That's weird since I'm not using `R` flag anywhere. Can you try this rule instead: `RewriteRule ^(Administration.*)$ /Frontend/$1 [L,NC]` ?

Comment: Hmmm also if I replace the rule with that rule it redirects me to: `http://localhost/Frontend/Administration/`

Comment: I suspect that is happening inside `index.php` `/Frontend/Administration/` directory.

Comment: I just tried to move over everything out of the directory and create an index.html just containing the word `works`. It still redirects me to `http://localhost/Frontend/Administration/` :(